# Microsoft Word: Find word case-sensitive only in sentence

Tags: microsoft-word

I know how to search for a specific word case-sensitive but how can I search for a specific word that is not at the start of a sentence but in the middle?

Answer (score 0):

Add a space before and after the term you want to search. Of course, the term "middle" is relative, the best you'll get is a word that isn't the first or last word in the sentence

Comment: That still finds words at the beginning of the sentence.

Comment: Then, it's pratically impossible to locate the "middle" of a sentence purely using Word. Since a sentence can span through multiple lines and the word count per sentence is variable. The method above assures that the word isn't first or the last one.